# Basic Theorem about prime ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

There is a sentence in the following proof (the second proof) that says " by a basic theorem about prime ideals we have...."

What is that basic theorem? Thank you.

[Intersection of prime ideals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49309/intersection-of-prime-ideals/49326#49326)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it is the fact that the prime ideals of a ring of fractions $S^{-1}R$ correspond bijectively to the prime ideals of $R$ which do not meet $S$.